# creating a link to images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery code which can wrap an img tag with a link:

My code is like this:

http://prntscr.com/iuw6hc

I will paste my HTML here but basically it is a loop of many items showing within each col.

```
<div class="car-item gray-bg text-center first" style="height: 357px;">        
        <div class="car-image">            
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http:///wp-content/uploads/2018/03/20180214_090633-265x190.jpg" alt="" width="265" height="190">            
            <div class="car-overlay-banner">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http:///cars/chevrolet-silverado-1500-lt-z71/" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="View"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
```

I am trying like this:

```
var wrapped = false;
    var original = $(".img-responsive");

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (!wrapped) {
            wrapped = true;
            var gURL = $('.car-overlay-banner').find('a').attr('href');
            $(".img-responsive").wrap("<a href=\"'+ gURL +'\"></a>");
        }
    });

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (wrapped) {
            wrapped = false;
            $(".img-responsive").parent().replaceWith(original);
        }
    });
```

Trying to use a href of car overlay to apply to the image too.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides a method named "wrap()", which can be used to insert any HTML structure in set of matched elements. In simple words, if you want put wrapper around your div element then you can use wrap() method. For example, you have a div with ID "Child".

```
<div id="Child"></div>
```

And want to wrap this div with any parent then you can use "wrap()" method to insert HTML.

```
$('#Child').wrap('<div id="Parent"></div>');

<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Same way, we will use the wrap() method to insert hyperlink to image tag so that the image becomes clickable. See below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgLogo").wrap('<a href="http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/"></a>');
});
```

In this example, I have used ID as selector but you can use class selector to find all the images with same class and then wrap them with  tag. You can also assign target="_blank" in the above  tag to open the link in new window.

Comment: Thanks, I am using wrap functionality but problem is there are many `col` related elements and i think i need to use `each` and use the `ul li a` `href` element to wrap that link and create an a link to the image tag, this is i am trying to do. i am getting stuck at that section

Answer (score 0):

I think you need code like this?

```
    var wrapped = false;
    var original = $(".img-responsive");

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (!wrapped) {
            var wrapped = true;

            // find link href in .car-image(img-responsive's parent) 
            var gURL = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');

            // use $(this) instead of $(".classname") to apply link only clicked image
            $(this).wrap("<a href=\""+ gURL +"\"></a>");
        }
    });

    $(".img-responsive").click(function(){
        if (wrapped) {
            var wrapped = false;
            $(this).parent().replaceWith(original);
        }
    });
```

Comment: use parent or children  for this:  `// find link href in .car-image(img-responsive's parent) 
            var gURL = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');`

Comment: i mean to say that do i need to use `parent()` or `children()`

Comment: and probably i need to use each because it will only attach to the first one and i want for all oof the looped items

Comment: it will attach link to only image you click.

Comment: if you click on third image in the list link will be attached on third image and so on